# Decrypting an apk and executing it at runtime

Tags: android, encryption, classloader

I have an apk encrypted with AES that is stored on my SDCard. When I input the passphrase from a dialog box, the file gets decrypted. This is my code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       

     AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle("Title");
        alert.setMessage("Message");

        // Set an EditText view to get user input 
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener()   {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        String value = input.getText().toString();
        try {
                Decrypt(value);
                Log.d(TAG,value);
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }});


        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int
    whichButton) {
                 // Canceled.
            }
            });

             alert.show();  
    }
    static void Decrypt(String Key) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
    NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {

    final String libPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +  
    "/encrypted.jar";
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(libPath);

    FileOutputStream fos = new  
    FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/decrypted.jar");
    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(Key.getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks /*originalKey*/);
    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
    int b;
    byte[] d = new byte[8];
    while((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
    fos.write(d, 0, b);
    }
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    cis.close();
    }
```

Now I want that when i click the OK button, not only the encrypted file is decrypted, it is also executed. How should I proceed? Should I use a custom class loader? Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "execute" an APK, any more than you can "execute" a ZIP file.

If by "execute" you mean "install", you can use `ACTION_VIEW` with an appropriate `Uri` and MIME type to the unencrypted APK file on external storage.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare for ur reply. I wanted to know if customized classloader can be used to run an encrypted file? If i extend dexclassloader?

Comment: @Shoaib: Since an encrypted APK is pointless IMHO, I have not investigated trying to loading classes from an encrypted APK. Anyone who wants to can decrypt that APK, after all, since your encryption key and algorithm are known by examining your main app.

Comment: Yes I know anyone who will have the key can get the source. Its more of an exercise than a reverse engineering problem :)thats Y i was asking for a suggestion on how to proceed